# JavaScript injection into Java WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Good evening,
I'm trying to get the following JavaScript snippet to run inside an WebView of an Android app. Trust me, I've studied several pages in here and I did it similarly.
That's the snippet:

```
function myFunction() {
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
newNode.setAttribute("style", "background-color: #FFF000;");
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

}

I'm working on a Browser app and I want to be able to highlight text passages. For that I've made a custom text selection menu, which contains an onClickListener.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    webView.loadUrl(
        "javascript:(function() { " +
            "var element = document.getElementById('hplogo');"
            + "element.parentNode.removeChild(element);" +
        "})()");
}});
```

That example works perfectly and I wanted to adapt it to my JavaScript snippet. My Code is the following:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                            "var selection = window.getSelection();" +
                            "var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);" +
                            "var newNode = document.createElement('span');"+
                            "sel.addRange(range);"+
                            "newNode.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #FFF000;');"+
                            "range.surroundContents(newNode);"+
                            "})()");
```

That drives me completely insane.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue that your javascript code has "sel.addRange" instead of "selection.addRange"

Comment: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);` might also be required.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, but that must have happened in the copy/paste process for this post. I changed it back, but still no luck. And JavaScript was enabled by me. Thanks Martin and John, but still no luck.

Comment: @DanielHegemann when you filter log-cat for `I/chromium`, what does it say?

Comment: John and Martin, what can I say, it works now. The "selection" thing was right and I've seen it, because Martin showed me, how to debug the WebView. Thanks for the help, guys. :)